# Print a specific time giving by the user python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the nearest value of a list giving the user input. In practice, the user gives me a time and I want to check if this value is in the list of the schedule, else I want to increment the minutes until I rescue a value of the list and then printing the time in a slot of thirty minutes. Here is my code. Can you help me showing what does not work? Thanks

```
def print_specific_time():
f = open("Bus 6 Lugano Stazione.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
d = defaultdict(list)
start = lines.index("Monday\n")
stop = lines.index("Saturday\n")
time = "07.35"
hour = time[0] + time[1]
minutes = time[3:]
for line in lines[start:stop]:
    line = line.strip(",")
    line = line.replace("\n","")
    line = line.replace(" ","")
    line = line.split("|")
    key = line[0]
    if len(line) == 2:
        d[key] += [line[1]]
    if minutes not in d[hour]:
        minutes = int(minutes) + 1
        minutes = str(minutes)
        print(minutes)
        if minutes in d[hour]:
            print(minutes)
            print(hour,d[hour])
                else:
            if minutes == '59':
                hour = int(hour)
                hour = hour + 1
                hour = "0" + str(hour)
                minutes = "00"
d = dict(d)
for key in d.keys():
    if key == hour:
        print(key,d[key])
```

In the file I have a list of the schedule all putting inside the dictionary. Here is the output I working on:

```
{'06': ['11', '26', '41', '56'], '12': ['06', '36'], '11': ['06', '36'], 
'07': ['11', '26', '41', '56'], '16': ['11', '26', '41', '56'], '14': ['06', '36'], 
'17': ['11', '26', '41', '56'], '20': ['05', '35'], '15': ['06', '36', '56'], 
'09': ['06', '36'], '21': ['05', '35'], '22': ['05', '35'], '23': ['05', '35'], 
'19': ['11', '40'], '08': ['11', '26', '41'], '13': ['06', '36'], '10': ['06', '36'], 
'18': ['11', '26', '41', '56']}
```

I explain it better. If, for example, the user put a time like 07.35 my program should print 07.41, 07.56 and nothing else (because there is no time after 7.56 in the slot of 30 minutes). Can you help me checking what's wrong? Thanks

EDIT
Ok. Now I'm able to print the slot of time of 07 o'clock (which is in part right) but I don't understand why python prints it only when the variable minutes is equal to '56' and not '41' which is in the list....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you overcomplicate it a bit. This one by one increasing is not neccessary. Here is my code to find the nearest time in your dictionary:

```
def find(time):
    start_hour, start_minute = map(int, time.split('.'))
    for h in range(start_hour, 24):
        hour = "{0:02d}".format(h)
        if hour in data.keys():
            line = data[hour]
            if h == start_hour:
                line = list(filter(lambda m: int(m) >= start_minute, line))
            if len(line) > 0:
                return '%s.%s' % (hour, line[0])
```

Here you can see it working: [fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/find-nearest-time-in-a-schedule/).

Edit: I modified the code to python3. (And the fiddle too.)

Edit2: I also made a version, that lists every time in the next half hour. [Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/find-times-in-the-next-half-hour).

Comment: I tried it in python but, of course, says that range is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it in python2. It's just `range` in python3.

Comment: another bug. filter has not property len()

Comment: Ok. I check it put a list in front of filter. Do it so I can assign your answer as the right one. Thanks man :)

Comment: I've just edited my answer. Did you try the current code? The result of `filter` is now converted to `list`.

Comment: And nope. I inserted the print you give me and the only result I have is 07:41

Comment: we should find another way to find the length of a filter and then I should also print all the result that starts from the time the user gives me until the 30 minutes after

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete edition with the code dividing in two functions. The code was done thanks to the helping of @zord:

```
def printed():
f = open("Bus 6 Lugano Stazione.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
d = defaultdict(list)
start = lines.index("Monday\n")
stop = lines.index("Saturday\n")
time = "07.35"
hour = time[0] + time[1]
minutes = time[3:]
for line in lines[start:stop]:
    line = line.strip(",")
    line = line.replace("\n","")
    line = line.replace(" ","")
    line = line.split("|")
    key = line[0]
    if len(line) == 2:
        d[key] += [line[1]]
d = dict(d)
return d

def find(time):
    data = printed()
    data2 = [int(h) * 60 + int(m) for h in data.keys() for m in data[h]]
    start_hour, start_minute = map(int, time.split('.'))
    start = start_hour * 60 + start_minute
    end = start + 30
    after = list(filter(lambda x: start <= x <= end, data2))
    return list(map(lambda x: '%02d.%02d' % (x // 60, x % 60), after))
```

Comment: I added a second fiddle to my answer. It may help you further.

Comment: give me a minute to merge and try